# How to keep 100% height + aspect ratio on full width background consisting of 8 different "prism" images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 8 's / background images - each image has the exact same size and is positioned the same.

Each  is defined with `background-size: cover` and `background: top center fixed`.

Fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/p19xu1er/

**My issue is that I want to show all of the prism image and still keep aspect ratio in a full width solution, and currently I experience on a bigger screen/resolution that especially prism marked with "4" will have it's bottom "joint"/"angle" line appear off-screen.**

If you resize the fiddle browser width to something high you can see this and if you re-size to something low you can see it appear.

I know this is because it's defined as `background: top center fixed` - however defining it to "bottom", will mis-align it.

Any suggestions on what I could do? I don't mind taking use of JS/Jquery if there's no other way.

Comment: I am fiddling with this a little. Is there a reason you can't simply turn it into one image?

Comment: Hi kiaaanabal - yup :/ Im going to animate a few elements above and under certain prisms, so need to be able to "sort" them with z-index

Comment: Gotcha. Still fiddling :) Hope I can figure something out for you!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind the shape of the prisms being skewed when the screen resizes, you could do something like this instead:

CSS:

```
div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

div img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="p1"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/Q8G7qJl.png"></div>
<div id="p2"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/KWi4kKy.png"></div>
<div id="p3"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/8bEneh3.png"></div>
<div id="p4"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/Dj47i8e.png"></div>
<div id="p5"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/BqEIfYC.png"></div>
<div id="p6"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/572QfZm.png"></div>
<div id="p7"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ZxEhjkO.png"></div>
<div id="p8"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/vYvYnjq.png"></div>
```

Cover is used when you're trying to completely fill in the background. It naturally hides excess. I tried using contain and that kept the proportions, but it didn't completely fill the screen's height. It would be hard to come up with a javascript solution because it's difficult to make changes based on the height/width of a background image.

I really hope this helps! You have a bit of a tricky situation on your hands.

Comment: Thanks for chipping in kiaaanabal. I did think of this one - however the problem here is when you resize the browser down to a certain point, then it will not hold 100% height and leave a gap.

Comment: Hmm, I am not seeing that issue. Is this something you are running into when you are using background-size: contain, or when you are using 100% height on an image? Could you provide a screen shot?

Comment: Its with your example. Notice the white gap: http://i.imgur.com/MpAsgNH.png - same behaviour in all browsers here

Comment: Strange. Do you still have your old css/markup in this example, or are you using only what I gave you?

Comment: only what you wrote :)

Comment: Okay. That is very strange, as I am not seeing that problem. Maybe you are cached? It doesn't make sense that an image with both height and width at 100% would leave any kind of gap. Trying holding shift while you refresh and let me know if it is still happening :/

Comment: still the same :) - but doesnt it make good sence that this will happen? The behaviour of an img height is to proportionally follow the adjusted width of the img. Would you be able to do a fiddle with your example, then I can just confirm if I see it there?

Comment: Oh, psh DUH! I forgot to add the height: 100%; width: 100%; to the div styling when I typed it in! Adding that should work haha :) Also, jsFiddle keeps timing out for me so I can't send you one, sorry :/

Comment: Ahh got it now :) It's basically the same as doing: background-size: 100% 100%; - Guess that's the alternatives I have - squeezed versus some clipping :/ Thanks a lot for the effort though!